# Custom Twitter login with Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, parse-platform

I've been stuck on how to implement a custom Twitter login with Parse for my Swift app for a while now. Most resources I've seen for Twitter login with iOS are for Objective-C, and I've tried changing the suggested solutions into Swift, but no luck so far. This is my current code:

```
@IBAction func twitterLogIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock( { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // apparently both user and currentUser are nil...
        if PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(PFUser.currentUser()) {
            var info: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json")
            var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: info)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, connectionError: NSError!) -> Void in
                if let d = data {
                    var dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                    // do stuff with user's profile info
                } else {
                    println("Apparently no Twitter response.")
                }
            })
        } else {
            println("Apparently failed login.")
        }
    })
}
```

This prints out `Apparently failed login.` I've also tried this:

```
PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock( { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let user = user {
        if user.isNew {
            println("User signed up and logged in with Twitter.")
            // put information in user object
            user.save()
        } else {
            println("User logged in with Twitter.")
        }
    } else {
        println("User was nil.")
    }
})
```

It printed out `User was nil.` And I also tried this:

```
if let twitter = PFTwitterUtils.twitter() {
    if twitter.userId != nil && twitter.screenName != nil && twitter.authToken != nil && twitter.authTokenSecret != nil {
        PFTwitterUtils.logInWithTwitterId(twitter.userId!, screenName: twitter.screenName!, authToken: twitter.authToken!, authTokenSecret: twitter.authTokenSecret!, block: {  (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    println("User signed up and logged in with Twitter.")
                    // put info in user object
                    user.save()
                } else {
                    println("User logged in with Twitter.")
                }
            } else {
                println("User was nil. Something went wrong. Did the user cancel the login?")
            }
        })
    } else {
        println("Couldn't access a Twitter account on this device.")
    }
} else {
    println("Couldn't find a Twitter account on this device.")
}
```

Which printed `Couldn't access a Twitter account on this device.` The only other option I know of right now is to use the built-in login view controller, but I'd rather use a custom one. How can I implement a custom Twitter login function?

Edit: I tried another method that didn't work yet again:

```
PFTwitterUtils.logInWithBlock( { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // apparently both user and currentUser are nil...
    println(2)
    if !(PFTwitterUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user)) {
        println(3)
        PFTwitterUtils.linkUser(user!, block: { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            println(4)
            if succeeded {
                println("User linked with Twitter.")
            }
        })
    }
    println(5)
    if let u = user {
        println(6)
        if u.isNew {
            println("User signed up and logged in with Twitter.")

            // put info in user object

            var info: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json")
            println(7)
            var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: info)
            println(8)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, connectionError: NSError!) -> Void in
                println(9)
                if let d = data {
                    println(10)
                    var dict: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                    // do stuff with this data
                } else {
                    println("Apparently no Twitter response.")
                }
            })
        } else {
            println("User logged in with Twitter.")
        }
    } else {
        println("User was nil.")
    }
})
```

This prints up to `3` and then complains of a nil optional value, most likely `user`.

Edit: I've been testing Fabric as a possible solution and although it provides a good Twitter login method, I can't figure out how to use it with Parse, specifically, how to create and handle a corresponding user object as I can't access the user's password. I'd much prefer to use `PFTwitterUtils` for the best integration with Parse, but I'm running out of options for that. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm running into this problem as well.  Did you ever find a solution?